# Char em função nao é reconhecida em c

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

Nao estou conseguindo fazer com que a variavel char seja comparavel e validada, a IDE fala que a variavel 'a' foi nao declarada, algum poderia me ajudar por favor

Faça uma função que receba as 3 notas de um aluno por parâmetro e uma letra. Se a
letra for A, calcula a média aritmética das notas do aluno, se for P, a sua média
ponderada (pesos: 5, 3 e 2). Utilize esta função no programa principal para retornar
a media ponderada de um aluno.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    float x,y,z;
    char e;
    printf("Digite as 3 notas e uma letra: ");
    scanf ("%f %f %f %c", &x, &y, &z, &e);
    float ers (float x,float y,float z, char e);
    printf("%f %f %f %c", ers(x,y,z,e));
    return 0;
}
float ers (float x,float y,float z, char e){
    if (e==a)
        float media = (x + y + z) / 3;
    else if (e==p)
        float media = (5*x + y*3 + z*2) / 10;
    return media;
}
```

Comment: Ou coloque a definição da função **antes** da main ou pelo menos coloque a assinatura da função. Neste `printf("%f %f %f %c", ers(x,y,z,e));` tem coisa faltando, talvez você quisesse `printf("%f %f %f %c %f", x, y, z, e, ers(x,y,z,e));`.

Comment: nao entendi, eu so queria guardar os valores das notas e a letra

Comment: Tudo me faz entender que você queira: `float ers (float x,float y,float z, char e){ if (e=='a') float media = (x + y + z) / 3; else if (e=='p') float media = (5*x + y*3 + z*2) / 10; return media; }`, já que não definiu as variáveis `a` e `p`.

Comment: isso mesmo, mas na funcao principal no começo eu quis guardar os valores das notas e uma letra, mas nao to conseguindo guardar a letra na variavel char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isto. Não entendi `ao to conseguindo guardar a letra na variável char`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
float ers (float, float, float, char);

int main () {
    float x,y,z;
    char e;
    printf("Digite as 3 notas e uma letra: ");
    scanf ("%f %f %f %c", &x, &y, &z, &e);
    printf("%f %f %f %c %f", x, y, z, e, ers(x,y,z,e));
    return 0;
}

float ers (float x, float y, float z, char e) {
    float media = 0;
    if (e == 'a' || e == 'A')
        media = (x + y + z) / 3;
    else if (e == 'p' || e == 'P')
        media = (5*x + y*3 + z*2) / 10;
    return media;
}
```

Comment: anonimo voce colocou a funcao no escopo global, poderia me dizer por que a preferencia?

Comment: Como já havia dito antes ou você coloca a definição da função ou a assinatura, ou protótipo, da função **antes** da main. Não é questão de escopo. é para o compilador resolver as referências.

Answer (score 2):

Na sua função **ers** você deve testar se o parâmetro recebido *e* é igual a 'A' ou 'P'.

Meu código exemplo abaixo está em C#, mas a ideia é a mesma: testar **e** com 'A' ou 'P' entre aspas simples, pois trata-se de tipo **char**.

```
using System;

namespace study
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char e = 'A';

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine( "Valor de e = {0}", e);

            if (e == 'A')
                Console.WriteLine("Cálculo por média aritmética!");
            else
                if (e == 'P')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cálculo por média ponderada!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Valor inválido para o tipo do cálculo!");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado Carlos